# Invalid values with Jooq when getting the primay keys for a table with column names containing upper case char

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, primary-key, jooq

Given the following table in Sqlite:

```
CREATE TABLE author (
    idOfAuthor   INTEGER (10) PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT (255) 
);
```

The method `table.getPrimaryKey()` returns an array of one element that is null. After changing the column name "idOfAuthor" to "id_of_author" it gets returned as expected.

Maybe the `field(String name)` method in `org.jooq.impl.Fields` class should use `equalsIgnoreCase` rather than just `equals`?

Comment: How do you obtain the `table` reference? Via the code generator, or via `org.jooq.Meta`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you're using the [Xerial JDBC driver](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc), which means you've run into this issue here:

https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/issues/167/databasemetadatagetprimarykeys-reports

There is a bug in the Xerial JDBC driver, which reports `DatabaseMetaData.getPrimaryKeys()` columns with all lower-case characters. This produces no primary key columns from jOOQ's `Table.getPrimaryKey()` call.

jOOQ's `org.jooq.Meta` uses JDBC `DatabaseMetaData` behind the scenes, and thus suffers from this problem indirectly, which could also be considered a bug ([#5097](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5097)), which should be fixed soon.